# divergence of integral of vector field

Tags: calculus, vectors

I'm having a hard time figuring out what,

$\nabla \cdot \int_0^1t$ **B**$(t$**x**$)dt$, where  **B**$($**x**) is a vector field s.t $\nabla \cdot B=0$

Comment: Are you trying to do this for general $\vec B$?

Comment: sorry i edited the question

Comment: Interchange of integral and derivative can be justified here, and the chain-rule applies to all forms of differentiation.